# How can I return a function with generic parameters that I do not know ahead of time?

Tags: c#, generics, closures

I want to call a function that generates a function, but I don't know the type parameter until I call the generated function like so:

```
ActionResult Foo() {
  IEnumerable<MyObject> list = GetList();

  var orderBy = OrderBy(list); // <-- HOW DO I WRITE OR DO THIS;

  switch(Request.QueryString["sortBy"]) {
    case "Name":
      return orderBy<string>(o => o.Name); // <-- SO I CAN MAKE THIS CALL
    case "TrackingNumber":
      return orderBy<int>(o => o.TrackingNumber); // <-- AND THIS ONE
    default:
      return View(list);
  }
}
```

I won't know the type of T until I call the returned function. I imagine something like this to generate the function, it wraps list in a closure so that I don't have to keep passing it around.

```
Func<Func<MyObject,T>,ActionResult> OrderBy<T>(IEnumerable<MyObject> list) {
  Func<Func<MyObject,T>, ActionResult> f = orderBy => {
     return View(Request.QueryString["sortDir"] == "d"
        ? list.OrderBy<MyObject, T>(orderBy)
        : list.OrderByDescending<MyObject, T>(orderBy));
  };
  return f;
}
```

Update:

I know there are better ways to do this. I want to know how I can wrap this list in a closure and return a function that has a generic type I don't know about ahead of time. For example, since I can't return the generic type function without knowing the type, is there some type I can replace it with?

Comment: Re: Your update. See my answer below. If you provide a `Func<MyObject, T>` the type you're talking about is automatically determined. For `o => o.Name` it's `string`, for `o => o.TrackingNumber` it's `int` and so on... You're implicitly specifying that type by choosing one of your class properties as the sort key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to identify the type that you care about that both types have in common.  In this case, it's `IComparable`.  You're sorting, and both `string`s and `int`s are `IComparable`.

You're also making the problem a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  You don't need so many `Func`'s that return `Func`'s.  You can simplify.

Also you don't want ASP.NET MVC classes to permeate your entire application.  Keep that stuff in the controllers and let the code that does the real work take parameters so it doesn't know it's running in ASP.NET MVC or in the web and can be unit tested.

```
    public static IEnumerable<MyObject> GetSortedList(string sortBy, bool sortAscending)
    {
        IEnumerable<MyObject> list = GetList();

        Func<MyObject, IComparable> keySelector;

        switch (sortBy)
        {
            case "Name":
                keySelector = o => o.Name;
                break;

            case "TrackingNumber":
                keySelector = o => o.TracingNumber;
                break;

            default:
                return list;
        }

        return sortAscending
                   ? list.OrderBy(keySelector)
                   : list.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
    }
```

Comment: Name and Tracking number are specific to the UI. That is why they are in the controller. My service layer knows nothing about these items. All that code I posted is in my controller. I also know that Request.QueryString is inferior, however I'm stuck maintaining an existing MVC application originally written in 1.0 and that is what I have to work with at the moment.

Comment: while your answer didn't actually answer my specific question, it is a MUCH better way to implement this. I was simply trying to see if I could accomplish this technique. In f# partial function applications are not uncommon. I keep trying to see what I can apply to my c# that I write at work everyday.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
ActionResult Foo() {
  IEnumerable<MyObject> list = GetList();

  switch(Request.QueryString["sortBy"]) {
    case "Name":
      return OrderBy(list, o => o.Name); // <-- SO I CAN MAKE THIS CALL
    case "TrackingNumber":
      return OrderBy(list, o => o.TrackingNumber); // <-- AND THIS ONE
    default:
      return View(list);
  }
}

ActionResult OrderBy<T>(IEnumerable<MyObject> list, Func<MyObject, T> orderBy) {
    return View(Request.QueryString["sortDir"] == "d"
        ? list.OrderBy<MyObject, T>(orderBy)
        : list.OrderByDescending<MyObject, T>(orderBy));
}
```

Comment: your answer doesn't wrap the list in a closure, it passes it to the method, defeating the purpose of my question.